# How can we use multiple Bootstrap CDN on a single Web page?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a project using Bootstrap. I want to use CDN 3.3.7 and 4.1 on a single Web page **because of an old feature that doesn't work using the 4.1 CDN** and only one CDN can be used at a time. So, is there any way by which I can use both at once or is there any other alternative?

Comment: try foundation may be that is good for you.  https://foundation.zurb.com/

Comment: Fix the old feature to work with the new version, or don't upgrade. Always try to include the minimum amount of code possible in your pages, and especially don't duplicate the same library twice.